# UWP Settings File

Tags: c#, uwp

Can I manually access to the UWP settings file and read it without using

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ToString();
```

Where is this file and what name?

Can I override this file with a new custom app.settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I manually access to the UWP settings file and read it without using
>   `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ToString();`

No. You have to use this API to read local settings.

> Where is this file and what name?

The settings file is in settings folder of the app data folder. You could see it in `C:\Users\your account\AppData\Local\Packages\your app's folder\Settings\settings.dat`

The appdata folder is hidden by default.

> Can I override this file with a new custom app.settings file?

No. You cannot rewrite it with your custom settings file. You could make your own settings file and save it in the local folder or other places. But I do not think it will be simpler than reading from `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values` directly. Because you need to open your settings file and read content from it, then you need to analysis it and get the specific value that you want, but if you use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values`, you could get the settings simply just like 'key-value' format.